# Find employee with lowest salary but also his department

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find employee with lowest salary- first and last name, gender and department.
I tried with this but I have problems adding department name.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, salary FROM salaries 
JOIN employees using(emp_no) where order by salary desc limit 0,1;
```

Any help?

[schema-link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMpBk.png)

Comment: what are you getting? is there an error? your sort order should be ASC if you want the lowest salary

Comment: So....how do you get someone's department given their name?

Comment: Your SQL's syntax is wrong. Please include your table structure too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you are missing a couple of joins among other things (like the department name in the field list):

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.gender, s.salary, d.dept_name 
FROM salaries AS s 
INNER JOIN employees AS e ON s.emp_no=e.emp_no 
INNER JOIN dept_emp AS de ON de.emp_no=e.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments AS d ON d.dept_no=de.dept_no 
ORDER BY s.salary ASC limit 0, 1
```

Comment: The OP hasn't posted the table structure, You'll still only end up with 1 row (when least salary per dept was requested), and left joins are going to be slower than inner joins. I don't think this accomplishes the goal.

Comment: OP posted the table structure in the link below his question.

Comment: And based on the query (get 1 employee with lowest salary) I wasn't terribly worried about speed, just trying to get an idea to build from

Comment: Ah, missed the link. Thanks.

Comment: Was least salary per dept requested?  I thought it was least salary, period, and OP wanted the department included as one of the fields returned.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet that's what I gathered also... this doesn't do any grouping and there is no where clause, so it will return the employee with the lowest salary along with their department...

Comment: Though, I think I should point out that the schema indicates much of this involves history tables. Your min salary in this case may not represent the current lowest salary.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking this is the employee with the lowest salary historically. The actual problem is potentially more interesting